# Templatizing images using gimp

Tags: python, gimp

My wife recently started a business making soap bars and the soap labels have quickly spiraled out of control into tons of diverging Gimp .xcf files.  The only difference between the files are the names of the product, description, and ingredients.  I'd like to make a template and produce the labels from a .xcf file and maybe a .xml or .ini file that has the text data.  I've been eyeing python-fu, but I'm not quite sure if it does what I'd like.  I'd like to stick to python where possible because it's simple.

Are there facilities in python + gimp to do what I'd like?  Could something similar be done in anything other than gimp?

**Edit**:  Additionally, I have to make pages of stickers to print, so some means of optimizing the number of stickers that can fit on a page (2d bin pack?) would be a big plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/library/) can quite easily read in an image, put some text on it, and write it back out. Use the [Image module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) to read and write, and the [ImageDraw module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm) to add the text.

I doubt that it can use the .xcf format though, you'll probably want to convert to .png.

Answer (score 1):

You can script GIMP in Python, and pretty much everything you can do o n the prgoram can be done via the API -- you can check for the available API functions in help->procedure browser.

To enable Python scripting in gimp 2.6 under Windows, you have to google for it -- Python, python gtk and one other package have to be installed before GIMP.

Python's PIL is fine for simple images, but it is weak in arttistic pixel manipulation, which is available with GIMP.